# Using Flask with PyMongo

Tags: python, mongodb, flask

I have Flask application, which looks like this:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)
from pymongo import MongoClient

def get_db():
    c = MongoClient()
    return c.mydb

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    db = get_db()
    db.foo.find_one(...)
    ...

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

Seems it works fine. But I'm not sure about one thing. I create a MongoClient instance (and connection to db) in every view call. But should I close connection?

Maybe  I should close connection after each view call, like this:

```
@app.before_request
def before_request():
    g.db = get_db()

@app.teardown_request
def teardown_request(exception):
    g.db.close()
```

How do you handle this stuff?

Answer (score 5):

[`MongoClient`](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/mongo_client.html#pymongo.mongo_client.MongoClient) has connection-pooling support built in, with a default size of 10.  So you should be creating one `MongoClient` instance that's left open and shared by all your view calls.

Comment: @un1t Your `MongoClient` instance basically becomes a global variable; so however you want to handle that.  Nothing flask-specific about it.

Comment: Don't do it per request - as thats a big overhead - have it in the module / global namespace.